# View YouTube videos in Gmail?

Tags: google-chrome, video, gmail, youtube

I have this annoying problem with YouTube videos, and the problem is the viewing experience. One or two weeks ago, when I clicked on YouTube video in Gmail (from "Your Personal YouTube Digest" newsletter) a pop-up with black frame with the video appeared and I was watching it from Gmail itself and not leaving and go directly to the video source.

Now when I click on a video, it redirects me to the source video. WTF? It was nice feature in Gmail that is gone now and I can't figure out! Does anyone have this feature built-in in Gmail right now? Does anyone have the same problem like me? I would be very grateful if someone have the time helping me.

Thank you.

p.s. I'm using Chrome v. 21.0.1180.75 m

Comment: I have also been wondering about this feature. I think I lost it during a chrome update but I'm not positive. I'm glad there's at least one other person who has noticed this. I can't find anything else out there about this feature. Have you figured anything out yet?

Answer (score 3):

This was a Google Labs feature as documented [here](http://gmailblog.blogspot.in/2009/03/new-in-labs-youtube-picasa-flickr-and.html) which no longer seems to exist.
I tried looking up on Gmail > settings > labs and could not find it.

Comment: This is so weird, I had this feature two weeks ago, and now I don't have it... Really weird. :\

**p.s. the Labs feature is now implemented in gmail, if you get mail with youtube link at the bottom of the mail you will have the preview of the video, but I don't want that. I was clicking on the video and then a pop-up with black frame appeared and the video in it.**